# How would you reference an array with objects in state to perform array methods on it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm having problems trying to delete one reply in my comment app project. The onClick function for the delete button for my reply keeps deleting the entire comment instead of just 'one' replies iterations that is in the reply array in state. It has to deal with how I'm referencing the state of the array of replies that I have. I'm not sure how to reference the state of the array due to my state.

I've already tried to reference state as a variable that will then reference the array in state.

```
//State for component
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      commentArray: [
        {
          message: "Hello",
          showReply: false,
          reply: [
            { replies: "Hi there." },
          ],
          id: 1
        }]
       }

//Function to splice one reply
handleRemoveReply = (index) => {
    let replyArray = this.state.commentArray.reply
    this.setState({
      reply: replyArray.splice(index, 1)
    })
  }
}
```

I'm expecting only one reply to delete, not the entire comment. With the things that I tried, I'm only able to delete the entire comment it seems. It keeps saying that the state is undefined, so it is a reference problem.

Comment: Is the `state` actually undefined or is `replyArray` undefined? According to your code, you're trying to grab a `reply` property of the array, `commentArray`. Also how are you passing `handleRemoveReply` to your component?

Comment: From what I tried out, I found out that it kept reading the reply arrary property as undefined and it wouldn't compile my app. I tried without referencing the reply array property to see if it would work with just commentArrary. It did work out, but it ended up deleting the entire comment instead of just one reply.

Comment: `replyArray` will always be `undefined` with the way you're initializing it since you're grabbing the property from an `array` and those don't have a `reply` property.

Comment: What would be a solution to go around the issue of `replyArray` being `undefined`?

Comment: you arent setting state correctly. you have an array of items. `this.state.commentArray.reply` is invalid. you need to pass the comment id to this handler function. then `const idx = this.state.commentArray.findIndex( comment => comment.id === id)` with that index you can properly reference the correct comment. `let replyArray = this.state.commentArray[idx].reply`

Comment: to access an item from the array its with square bracket notation. `[]` so `commentArray[0]` would be the first item in the array. Think of it like an object with sequential numerical keys :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell your not actually interacting with the state correctly for your state data structure. You must first get the replyArray for the given comment, and then you need to set the state back to the origonal data structure. Also to note is that splice performs the splice operation on the array however returns the object removed. Hence unless you want to set the state to what was removed you want to first splice the array and then set the state to the new result.

```
//Function to splice one reply
handleRemoveReply = (index) => {
    let replyArray = this.state.commentArray.reply
    this.setState({
      reply: replyArray.splice(index, 1)
    })
  }
}
```

Try this:

```
// Also pass what comment index you are interacting with
handleRemoveReply = (commentIndex, index) => {
    const commentArray = [...this.state.commentArray]
    commentArray[commentIndex].reply.splice(index, 1)

    this.setState({
      commentArray
    })
  }
}
```

Edit: updated to copy state instead of directly mutate it

Comment: you are mutating state here. This is excessively dangerous. Instead make a copy of your state objects before applying methods / assignments that will mutate it.

Comment: or just the extend notation `...` :)

Comment: I mean ideally would be using the useReducer hook haha

Comment: haha, im not a huge fan of hooks :P but thats a long story. You had bugs in your code with object assign. You weren't using it correctly, I just updated to clean it up a bit :)

Comment: Ahh thanks, I don't tend to use it too often. I had considered putting it into one line but didn't know if that would be too dense. Is the `commentArray` being a "const" not going to be annoyed when you splice it? Otherwise looks great

Comment: Well you aren't reassigning it, you're just mutating a copy, the memory doesn't change :)

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that, thanks for the info :)

Comment: State is still being mutated here with the edits above - you will need to create copies all the way down through the state structure, not just a copy of the `commentArray` by spreading the items of the array into a new array. E.g. if `commentIndex = 0` then `this.state.commentArray[0] === prevState.commentArray[0]` after calling `handleRemoveReply(0, 0)` which will break pure components that take comments as props.